# Unable to connect internet inside the docker containers in MAC machine

Tags: docker, kubernetes, minikube, zalenium

I am trying to run tests inside the containers (selenium nodes). I used kubernetes to orchestrate the containers.

[image]

[image]

Tried updating the `Docker subnet` too

[image]

**Note:** Restarting docker didn't help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Everything worked well after I `uninstall`, `reinstall`, `delete` and `start` minikube

probably the newer version had some fix; but am not sure why it wasn't working before

```
brew cask uninstall minikube
brew cask install minikube

minikube delete
minikube start
```

Answer (score 2):

Check if firewall is enabled. if so, stop and disable the firewall

Comment: Yes, it is ON; however, I have no options to stop it

Comment: is there anyway that I can bypass the docker machine ip; like whitelisting so that it can allow internet

Comment: you must be in a restricted network. can you add HTTP_PROXY and HTTPS_PROXY environment variables to the container environment and check

Comment: sure; let me try :)